# VS2017 Build all solutions when pressing F5 buy only execute one

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on a project that has a DLL and a .exe that loads it. Whenever I press F5, it compiles the .exe project(which is set as default) but it does not compile the DLL one(which is the one with the most changes to).

I've tried the "Multiple Startup Projects" feature in the solution's properties, does force the DLL project to compile, but it always pops a message box saying it can't launch a DLL file.

Is there anyway I can tell Visual Studio to build the .exe and the .DLL whenever I press F5(or click the button) but only start the .exe one?

Comment: did you try **set as startup project**? you can set as startup project by right click on your project

Comment: My .exe project is the startup project, but I want visual studio to compile the DLL before starting the .exe(the startup project)

Comment: Do you have the DLL project added as a dependency? Or do you just have the DLL file itself.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks. I completly forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS should build any projects that it recognizes as out of date.  If the DLL project is not referenced by the EXE project, then you can add an explicit build dependency by right-clicking on the solution and picking `Project Dependencies` from the context menu.  This lets you specify build dependencies before a given project build (in addition to relationships implied though project references).